# Centos 5 SAS controller

Tags: centos, sas, controller

NOC tech told me this:

I am having troubles loading this server. I set up the HDD in the RAID controller however it does not show up when I try to install CentOS. A quick look at SuperMicro's website shows that this board (X7DCL-3) does not support CentOS using the SAS drives.

http://www.supermicro.com/support/resources/OS/5400_5100.cfm

---

Anyone have any idea about this? I need 64bit drivers for Centos 5 64bit o/s for this SAS controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?viewmode=thread&topic_id=19447&forum=39), CentOS 5.2 x64 should work, but 5.3 won't. Have them try loading 5.2.

Comment: I've already tried 5.2 Centos and it still does not show up when I am to select a disk. The drivers do not seem to be included on the disk. I did some searching and attempted to find some drivers in order to manually load, using hints from the link that you provided, however none of them seem to work either.

Comment: Did you see this thread: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-742188.html?

"X7DCL-3 supports only software RAID or non-RAID on SAS drives! if you need hardware RAID, then you still need to install a standalone hardware RAID card, and your cost will be much higher than just using X7DCL-I board (no on-board SAS ports) to start with."

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're going to need a real controller in there. anything based on LSI (IBM/Dell/LSI/HP/etc) is supported with the megaraid driver